# Smiles bot in Lua: matching text

Tags: string, lua, string-matching

This is my bot, who copies smilies in game chat.

The smiles it copies are saved in the table called "emoticons". If someone writes ":)", the bot writes ":)" and so on

The code inside the loop is for this: if someone writes, for example, ">:)", you have to make the script copy ">:)" and not just ":)"

`CreateFrame`, `RegisterEvent`, `SetScript` and `SendChatMessage` are in-game built Lua API

```
local emoticons = { 
    ":)", "(:", ":))", ">:)", "0:)", ":D", ":]", ":)))", "=]", "?_?", "+.+", ":P", ":3", "^^", "roar", ":V", "D:", ":C", ".D", ".)", "o_o", 
    "^-^", ":PPP", ":DDD", ":D:D:D", ":DDDD", ":D:D:D:D", ":DDDDD", ":d", ":L", "<O>_<O>", "o/", "+_+", "?_?", "*0*", ":}", ";)", ":))))", "o.o", "<.<''", ":|", 
    ":-)", "^^^^", ":D:D:D:D:D:D", ":D :D :D", "^^^", ":c", ";]", ":9", ">:|", ">.<", ";3", ";P", "T_T", ":3c", ":)))))", 
    "^^^^^" }

local f = CreateFrame("Frame")
f:RegisterEvent("CHAT_MSG_GUILD")
f:SetScript("OnEvent", function(self, event, text, playerName, _, channelName, playerName2, _, _, channelIndex)
    local msg
    local n = 0 
        for x, key in ipairs(emoticons) do
            local l = string.len(emoticons[x])
                if (string.sub(text, -l) == emoticons[x]) then
                    if (l > n) then
                        msg = emoticons[x]
                        n = l
                    end
                end
        end
    if (msg) and (playerName ~= UnitName("player")) then
        if (event == "CHAT_MSG_GUILD") then SendChatMessage(msg, "GUILD", nil, channelIndex) end
    end
end)
```

Is there any way to improve it? For example, if someone writes

"^^^^^^"

the bot copies

"^^^^^"

which would be the same with one less "^" as it was stored in the table

My goal is that if someone writes, for example, "^^^^^^" and it is not registered in the table, the script will not respond

Comment: also why do you have ":D :D :D" ? there seem to be no difference to simply responding to three single :D.  this is complicating things for no obvious reason

Comment: how do you treat multiple emoticons in the message? you seem to respond with the last match

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off learning how to use [string.gmatch](http://%20http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch)

As an example, let's say you only store one instance of `':D'` in your emoticons table. You can iterate through the matches and respond in kind. Here's a small example:

```lua
local text = ':D:D:D'
local count = 0
for w in string.gmatch(text, ':D') do
   count = count + 1
end
if count > 0 then
    local response = ''
    for i = 1, count do
        response = response .. ':D'
    end
    print(response) -- prints ':D:D:D'
end
```

This doesn't handle every case, but hopefully it can help you get started
:D